# Powershell integer parameter validation with multiple ranges

Tags: powershell

I know you can declare an integer parameter that only accepts values within a specific range:

```
[Parameter()][ValidateRange(1024,66535)]$Port
```

Is it possible to validate parameter input for several ranges? For example, say I want to allow port inputs to be 1 through 80, 135 through 445, and 1024 through 65535, I could do it with:

```
[Parameter()][ValidateRange(1,66535)]$Port

if ((($Port -gt 80) -and ($Port -lt 135)) -or (($Port -gt 445) -and ($Port -lt 1024))) {
    
    Write-Error "Incorrect input, please enter a value between 1-80, 135-445, or 1024-65535"
    break

}
```

However that doesn't strike me as a particularly neat way of doing things. `ValidateSet()` also can't take number ranges like 1024..65535. Anyone have a better idea of input validation for multiple integer ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely implement your custom [`ValidateRange` attribute declaration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validaterange-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.2) by creating a [`class`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_classes?view=powershell-7.2) that inherits from the [`ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute` Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validateargumentsattribute?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). Here is a little example:

```bash
class ValidateCustomRange : Management.Automation.ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute {
    [void] ValidateElement([object] $Element) {
        if($Element -gt 80 -and $Element -lt 135 -or $Element -gt 445 -and $Element -lt 1024) {
            throw [Management.Automation.MetadataException]::new(
                'Invalid range! Must be ...your call here :)'
            )
        }
    }
}

function Test-Range {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateCustomRange()]
        [int] $Port
    )
}

Test-Range 80 # All good!
Test-Range 81 # Error
```

Comment: Always quick answers from you, appreciated! This one worked exactly as expected :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73656937/45375) with an alternative that may be of interest for making a function or script *self-contained*:

Using the [`[ValidateScript()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ValidateScriptAttribute) allows you to specify a *script block* for validation, in which you can refer to the argument given via `$_`

- That way you don't need to declare a separate class, which in a stand-alone *script* you wouldn't be able to reference in your script's `param(...)` block, which must come *first* in the file.
- Conversely, however, if you're authoring a *module*, where you can package your classes along with the exported functions that use them, Santiago's [`ValidateEnumeratedArgumentsAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.validateargumentsattribute)-based `class` solution may be preferable.

A solution that also works in ***Windows PowerShell*** (`throw` is used to provide a meaningful custom error message):

```bash
function foo {
 param(
   [ValidateScript({ 
     if ($_ -in 1..80 + 135..445 + 1024..65535) { return $true }
     throw "Value $_ is not between 1 and 80, 135 and 445, or 1024 and 65535."
   })]
   $Port
 )
 $Port # Sample output: echo the port given, if it passed validation
}

foo 10  # OK
foo 100 # Fails validation.
```

A simplified solution that requires ***PowerShell (Core) 7+***, where you can now use an `ErrorMessage` property to provide a custom error message:

```bash
# PS v7+, using the ErrorMessage property.
function foo {
 param(
   [ValidateScript(
     { $_ -in 1..80 + 135..445 + 1024..65535 },
     ErrorMessage = 'Value {0} is not between 1 and 80, 135 and 445, or 1024 and 65535.'
   )]
   $Port
 )
 $Port # Sample output: echo the port given, if it passed validation
}

foo 10  # OK
foo 100 # Fails validation.
```

Comment: OH! Yeah I think this is better for my application, I'm only providing the modules to my colleagues and I can't ensure that they will use the whole package every time. I had totally forgotten about ValidateScript(), thank you!